Fetching local API with Nextjs 14 fetch fail
I'm quite new to Nextjs. I'm trying to make a server side fetch call to my api at http://api.localdomain.test/v1/page. This is my component app/[page]/page.jsx
const getPage = async () => {
    //const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'); // works
    const response = await fetch('http://api.localdomain.test/v1/page');
    if(!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }
    return response.json();
}

export default async function Page() {
    const page = await getPage();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <div>
                {JSON.stringify(page)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

Using url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users works, but http://api.localdomain.test/v1/page doesn't. This is my error response:
2024-05-19 08:04:35  ⨯ TypeError: fetch failed
2024-05-19 08:04:35     at async getPage ([page]/page.jsx:10:22)
2024-05-19 08:04:35     at async Page ([page]/page.jsx:17:18)
2024-05-19 08:04:35 digest: "566749960"
2024-05-19 08:04:35 Cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
2024-05-19 08:04:35     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1606:16)
2024-05-19 08:04:35     at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
2024-05-19 08:04:35   errno: -111,
2024-05-19 08:04:35   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2024-05-19 08:04:35   syscall: 'connect',
2024-05-19 08:04:35   address: '127.0.0.1',
2024-05-19 08:04:35   port: 80
2024-05-19 08:04:35 }
2024-05-19 08:04:35  GET /page 500 in 4257ms
2024-05-19 08:04:35  GET /_next/webpack-hmr 404 in 24ms
2024-05-19 08:04:35  GET /_next/webpack-hmr 404 in 21ms
2024-05-19 08:12:15  ✓ Compiled in 517ms (1313 modules)
2024-05-19 08:12:34  ✓ Compiled in 216ms (1265 modules)

In a client side component I can fetch data this way
return axios.get('/v1/page');

With Axios
import Axios from 'axios';

const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    withXSRFToken: true,
})

export default axios


When you run return axios.get('/v1/page'); this snippet in client, could you compare the full url in the network tab of the browser developer console with the url in the server side

I can visit the url in browser and did a copy and past first de fetch method.
